# Docker compose: additional property dockerfile_inline is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

services.tomcat.build Additional property dockerfile_inline is not allowed.

```
version: "3"
services:

  tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile_inline: |
        FROM tomcat:9.0.73-jdk11-corretto-al2
        COPY example.war /var/local/tomcat/webapps/
      
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like this feature not supported yet (or you need something very fresh)

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.17.0

[image]

Comment: > docker --version: current Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243.  It was installed by docker desktop on windows: currently on version 4.17.1 (101757). The latest version is 4.18.0 (104112). Should upgrade docker desktop? thanks.

Comment: updated docker to the new version. worked.

Comment: What exactly was your error? I'm getting this when trying it:  "failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile:"  It seems like it's looking for the Dockerfile even though it's inline...